# Talend executing parallel merge statements on a single table in snowflake with 32 threads, the process is failing

Tags: multithreading, talend, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, locks, parallel-execution

With Talend executing parallel merge statements on a single table in snowflake with 32 threads, the process is failing showing error as "statement X' was aborted because the number of waiters for this lock exceeds the 20 statements limit".

Now my question is how can I efficiently use the parallel threads in Talend so that it should not cross this limit in snowflake?

Will 20 thread always create a maximum of 20 locked transaction (1 holding, 19 waiting) at a particular timestamp or can it go beyond 20?

Are the locks in snowflake directly proportional to the number of DMLs (in these case merge statements) at any particular timestamp?

How much time snowflake waits for the waiting locks to wait to get the other holding lock to finish before it automatically aborts? Since the others DMLs are waiting to get the exclusive lock, which means they are being idle so will snowflake abort the transactions after 4 hours of it's start, if the holding transactions didn't complete in 4 hours?

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't just run 1 large MERGE statement?  That'd be your most efficient way to do this.

Comment: There are multiple CDC operations (for around 200 tables) happening based on a composite key.  Now the table in question is a kind of audit table. To capture the details of each of the CDC operation, different merge statements are invoked to update the audit table. If I change all these merges to a single merge, this means I have to create a temp table to hold all details and then merge it with main table. Wouldn’t that be sequential and slower than the parallel runs?

Comment: If you insert the data into a temp table, you can do that in parallel.  And then a single MERGE statement would be much faster than doing multiple in parallel.  For one, you're not really doing anything in parallel, since they will block each other.  And two, the way Snowflake inserts and updates is different from other system, and will be faster to do it all at once.

Comment: Thanks @MikeWalton for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

if you really think you need more waiters than 20 you can always write to the Snowflake support and ask for the value to be increased.

As far as the transaction limits go - to have snowflake abort anything you need to set the timeout:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#lock-timeout
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#statement-timeout-in-seconds
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#statement-queued-timeout-in-seconds

Comment: Yeah it can be done but before increasing the limit, could you help me clarify the question regarding DML statements and the lock count at a particular timestamp.

Comment: sorry, but sure what info you're looking for. Generally there's 1 lock and X waiters based on the situation you described. But this is for this single lock - any other lock has it's own limit of 20

Comment: While the lock was in place, I saw locks both at partition and table (1+1) and waiters on both. Can you please clarify if this means naturally there would be two locks on an object, 1 at partition level and another at table level at any given time? would both has limit of 20 or altogether it's 20?

Comment: each is 20. Partition-level lock is "lower" than table. When your table gets big enough it's sometimes not needed to lock the entire table to modify data as needed.